# Using Round/Ceiling/Floor function with IIF in SSRS expression

Tags: sql, sql-server, reporting-services, reportbuilder3.0, reportbuilder

In my, SSRS report the values for Success and Fail fields are supposed to together add up to 100. But as seen below the sum of the `Success` and `Fail` fields is falling short of 100 due to some round-off error.
[image]

I have used this expression to show the result for `Success`.

```
    =IIF(Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnSuccess.Value +Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnFail.Value =0, 
    100,Fields!NearlyAlways_On_SLO_Success.Value) & "%," & Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnSuccess.Value
```

The expression for `Fail` is below.

```
    =(Fields!NearlyAlways_On_SLO_Fail.Value) & "%," & Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnFail.Value
```

I have tried the following approaches to no avail.

1. From text box properties, try to set the value of percentage decimal points to 2.
2. Adding the Round/Ceiling/Floor function to the value of `Fields!NearlyAlways_On_SLO_Success.Value`.

Any help is truly appreciated.

Comment: Why have you tagged both 2008 *and* 2012 here? Which are you *really* using? note that both are *completely* unsupported.

Comment: We are using 2012 version.

Comment: Some sample data to reproduce your example would help

Comment: Why would you expect the rounded values to add up to 100? e.g.: `100/3 = 33.333'` (recurring), but `round(100/3, 0) + round(100/3, 0) + round(100/3, 0) = 99`. Ceiling, Floor, Round and Average are all destructive operations.

Comment: I intended to round up either `Success` and round down `Fail` as then it would give me the sum of 100 for both, that's my requirement from the report.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because Success and Fail must necessarily partition the data, try displaying the FAIL percent as the remainder from the SUCCESS percent

```
= IIF(Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnSuccess.Value 
   + Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnFail.Value = 0
   , 0, 100 - Fields!NearlyAlways_On_SLO_Success.Value
  ) & "%," & Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnFail.Value
```

If that doesn't work, you can try adjusting how you calculate `NearlyAlways_On_SLO_Fail`, but try this first and report back

EDIT: Responding to comment from @OrcaZep I'm adding a more complex formula that calculates the percentages from the COUNT values so we have control of rounding in SSRS instead of SQL.

Note that this way we have to provide updated formulas for both SUCCESS and FAIL, otherwise they might not total 100. And the formula for SUCCESS must be reproduced inside the formula for FAIL, we can't rely on the passed in calculations other than COUNT.

Formula for SUCCESS (locally calculated with CEILING)

```
= IIF(Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnSuccess.Value 
      + Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnFail.Value = 0
   , 100
   , Ceiling(100*Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnSuccess.Value / (Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnSuccess.Value 
      + Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnFail.Value))
   )
```

Formula for FAIL (Calculated from local SUCCESS)

```
= IIF(Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnSuccess.Value 
      + Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnFail.Value = 0
   , 0
   , 100 - Ceiling(100 * Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnSuccess.Value / (Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnSuccess.Value 
      + Fields!CountNearlyAlwaysOnFail.Value))
   )
```

Here's the raw data for my test

```
with cteTest as (
   SELECT * FROM (VALUES ('T01',7,8)
      , ('T02',8, 7), ('T03',0, 0)
      , ('T04',51, 50), ('T05',50, 51)
   ) as Smpl(RowName, CountNearlyAlwaysOnSuccess
      , CountNearlyAlwaysOnFail)
) SELECT * FROM cteTest
```

The output looks like this. Note that I increased the decimal precision to show it was discarding the decimal part of the percentage, this works equally well with decimal precision of 0 decimal places.

| Name | Success | Fail | RawSuccess | RawFail | CalcSuccess | CalcFail |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T01 | 7 | 8 | 0.4667 | 0.5333 | 47.00 | 53.00 |
| T02 | 8 | 7 | 0.5333 | 0.4667 | 54.00 | 46.00 |
| T03 | 0 | 0 | #DIV/0! | #DIV/0! | 100.00 | 0.00 |
| T04 | 51 | 50 | 0.5050 | 0.4950 | 51.00 | 49.00 |
| T05 | 50 | 51 | 0.4950 | 0.5050 | 50.00 | 50.00 |

Comment: This solution is working for now but I noticed that for example if the value of the 'success' field is 7 and 'Fail' is 8 then according to this expression it shows the respective percentage as 46 and 54, whereas ideally, it should have shown 47 and 53 after rounding off properly.

Comment: @OrcaZep, do you have the ability to view and/or change the calculation on the SQL end for `NearlyAlways_On_SLO_Success` and if so can you post it here (and tag me in a comment so I get notification)? I suspect the problem is there, though we might be able to fix it entirely on the SSRS side if you can't get at the SQL.

Comment: yes I thought so too that SQL code could resolve the problem at hand but I was apprehensive of altering the code there because it was a bit complex for me. But I am still going to copy the SQL code for `NearlyAlways_On_SLO_Success` here:

Comment: `Isnull((CONVERT(DECIMAL(5,0),Count(CASE WHEN R.PrimaryApplicationType ='NearlyAlwaysOn' AND R.ActionSLO = 'Open - Within Target' Then 1 END) * 100 /NULLIF(Count(CASE WHEN R.PrimaryApplicationType ='NearlyAlwaysOn' Then 1 END),0))),0) AS 'NearlyAlways_On_SLO_Success'`

Comment: OK @OrcaZep, that's probably more complex than we want to mess with on the SQL side (though we could and it would probably be the better place to do it), so I updated my solution to include a full recalc (with CELING on the SUCCESS) within SSRS. Try it out and report back if it provides the answers you're looking for on all use cases.